# Unity3d UI Buttons MultiTouch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a game in which there are two ui buttons on the game. I am using unity 4.6 to build this.I have one button that will turn my player blue and another that will turn the player yellow. I need it so when both are pressed my player will turn green. I haven't found much on multitouch with these UI buttons. I would love the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the usual button paradigm, the button completes the action when the user presses the button and then ends the press while the pointer (mouse or finger) still on the button. This is called "click". You are saying that you need this event to happen while the buttons are still pressed — so, you want them to react to press-down event, not the click event. Therefore, they are no longer classical buttons, and you probably shouldn't use Unity's UI Button for this functionality. If you'd use buttons for that, when the user first pressed on both buttons, you'd get green color, but when he then stopped touching them, you'd finally get yellow or blue player.

Instead, use the [EventTrigger](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html) component on each individual "pseudo-button" to register press-down events, and a separate custom component that would implement your logic. Essentially, the only way to realize your requirements without them being contradictory, is to assign the yellow color when the player is pressing down both "pseudo-buttons" and assign other colors when the player lifts his fingers up from either of them — but given that this particular touch wasn't used to trigger the yellow color.